# Video Streaming in Media Element using Silverlight Webpart in SharePoint Online (O365)

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, video-streaming

I have created a project which uses media element to play the video from Windows azure in silverlight.
I had created the .xap of the project and embedded in silverlight webpart in Sharepoint online.
i found everthing working except video streaming
How to stream the video in silverlight webpart in Sharepoint online?
Thanks in advance.
Srithar

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee414275.aspx

says that "SharePoint Server 2010 does not support live streaming of audio or video content."